# Unit test error with mocha and chai Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, chai, web3js

My code:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { interface,bytecode} = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach( async() => {
accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
  .deploy({data: bytecode,arguments:['Hi There !'] })
  .send({from: accounts[0], gas:'1000000'});
});

describe("inbox", () => {
it('deploys a contract', () => {
    console.log(inbox);
 })
})
```

The error while running it using npm run test:

> `shreyas@shreyas-Inspiron-3520:~/inbox$ npm run test

> inbox@1.0.0-beta.55 test /home/shreyas/inbox
> mocha

> inbox
> 1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract"

> 0 passing (2s)
> 1 failing

> 1. "before each" hook for "deploys a contract":
>    Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
>    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
>    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)

Git Repository of my project: https://github.com/shreyasjain/inbox

Comment: are you sure this call finishes? `await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
  .deploy({data: bytecode,arguments:['Hi There !'] })
  .send({from: accounts[0], gas:'1000000'});`

Comment: no...i am not  sure...

Comment: can you add a console log to see if it finish

Comment: try calling `done()` in your hook. `beforeEach( async(done) => { ... done()}`

Comment: done that, but still not working

Comment: one more thing: in the above code, myContract.deploy() is working fine, but myContract.deploy().send() is not. Any solution???